# Is it possible to to generate multiple rows based on the column list by single ng-repeat?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, json

I want to create 3 rows based on the columnList which contains 3 types of values i.e caption, shortCaption and columnName.

```
[{
    caption : "First Name",
    shortCaption: "FN",
    columnName : "FIRST_NAME"
},{
    caption : "Last Name",
    shortCaption: "LN",
    columnName : "LAST_NAME"
}
]
```

Currently i am generating table cell by iterating columnList with ng-repeat inside each row, here i am using `ng-repeat` three times which can be cause slowness, Is it possible to use `ng-repeat` only once at a time and generate all three rows, i also tried to use `ng-repeat-start` and `ng-repeat-end` but failed to get the output.

```
<tr>
<th  ng-repeat="column in columnList">
    {{column.caption}}
</th>
</tr>
<tr>
<th  ng-repeat="column in columnList">
    {{column.shortCaption}}
</th>
</tr>
<tr>
<th  ng-repeat="column in columnList">
    {{column.columnName}}
</th>
</tr>
```

http://plnkr.co/n0XKuwxOY8e1zjLfYwFI

Comment: what do you mean with, it can cause slowness? You could rebuild your UI by using divs instead of a real table, I guess that could work to do only one repeat

Comment: is it possible to generate without divs?

Comment: Can you show the full generation of the table and the full (example) content of the data you are trying to render?

Comment: i have updated my question with plnkr link

Answer (score 1):

template.html

```
<tr ng-repeat="column in columnList">
    <td ng-repeat="key in getKeys()" ng-bind="::column[key]"></td>
</tr>
```

Controller.js

```
$scope.getKeys = function() {
    return ['caption', 'shortCaption', 'columnName'];
}
```

This uses the `ng-repeat` twice. If you are sure about the keys of the objects in your column list, you can eliminate the 2nd `ng-repeat` - but the performance improvement will be negligible unless you have more than 500+ rows.

Comment: thanks for your answer, i have updated my answer with plnkr link of my example. could you update example with your solution.